# Compare Sno and display complete infromation form SQL Server Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm developing auction site as my University Final year project.
But I'm stuck in one problem i-e Which I click "View Details" hyperlink in Grid-view, it should compare Sno and Display its complete information present in SQL Server Table in new Tab.
Screenshot of Grid-view

[image]

```
string query1 = "select * from Sell ";
```

What condition I should apply in the above SQL Query to perform my task

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not really clear what you are asking but I would venture to guess that you want to include a where clause in your query. Most likely using the primary key of your table.

Comment: You got it right Sean.How can we do that? Can you explain this Please.   Thanks in Advance

Comment: How can you add a where clause? You start by typing "where YourPrimaryKeyColumn = SelectedRowsPrimaryKey".

Comment: Thanks for your response Sean. Can you elaborate it more for better understanding please?

Comment: I don't how much elaboration is needed here. You would create a where clause for your query. And that where clause contains row details similar to your Bid Now link.

Comment: Bid Now link is different. On clicking View Details there must be different information for each row like Title,Price etc must be change from another. Can you please give a full SQL query here? Thanks alot for giving your time

Comment: Are you saying the Bid Now link is the exact same on each row? How would you know which item is being bid on? Look up hyperlinks in a datagrid on google. This is incredibly easy to do.

Comment: Yes.Bid Now is same for each row but View Details is different for each row.  Bid Now is done but I'm stuck in View Details

Comment: Why is Bid Now the same for each row? That seems horribly wrong. Don't you need to know which item the user is bidding on? For the details link are you going to a new page? If so, just pass the primary key in the query string? There are so many ways to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question, it sounds like you are wanting to have a link view details link clicked that retrieves the data from you sql database for the specific item being clicked.

If this is the case you are first going to want to get your sql data into a string which takes a couple more steps then what your are attempting in your example.

Instead try using a stored procedure which takes a parameter being the item your fetching and use this model:

```
public string StringFromDatabase()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = null;

        try
        {
            var dataSet = new DataSet();

            connection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Goes Here");
            connection.Open();

            var command = new SqlCommand("Your Stored Procedure Name Goes Here", connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = command };

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            return dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Item"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. What should come in for  "Your Stored Procedure Name Goes Here" and What "Item" in return dataset code line